# How to change the last list element to -1?

Tags: python

Write a function that accepts a list. The function should change the element of a list with a max value on its right side. The last element of a list should be changed to -1.
Input: [17, 18, 5, 4, 6, 1]
Output: [18, 6, 6, 6, 1,−1]
I was able to do the first part but I can't seem to change the value of the last element to -1.

```
def list_change(lista):
    for i in range(0, len(lista)):
        if i == (len(lista) - 1):
            x = 0 - 1
            lista[i] = lista[x]
        else:
            tmax = -100000000
            for j in range(i + 1, len(lista)):
                if lista[j] > tmax:
                    lista[i] = lista[j]
                    tmax = lista[j]
    print(lista)


list_change([17, 18, 5, 4, 6, 1])
```

Comment: `lista [-1] = -1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy, change the last element using its index -

```
def list_change(lista):
    for i in range(0, len(lista)):
        if i == (len(lista) - 1):
            x = 0 - 1
            lista[i] = lista[x]
        else:
            tmax = -100000000
            for j in range(i + 1, len(lista)):
                if lista[j] > tmax:
                    lista[i] = lista[j]
                    tmax = lista[j]
    lista[-1] = -1 # Get the last element and change it.
    print(lista)


list_change([17, 18, 5, 4, 6, 1])
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the last element of the list, use the list[-1] syntax. The list[-n] syntax gets the nth-to-last element. So list[-1] gets the last element, list[-2] gets the second to last.

```
list[-1] = -1
```

Edit: first of all, don't use list as a variable, `list` is used to create a new list as `list(...)` as an alternative to `[...]`. Secondly, check the list is not empty before making the aforementioned call.

So if variable `x` is referencing a `list` object

```
if not x:
    x.append(elem)
else:
    x[-1] = elem
```

Comment: It's just a help for others who may ask the same question, and btw I gave the answer in the first part.